# How to insert key value pairs to new unordered_map<int, int>* (pointer) in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, unordered-map

I have an unordered_map pointer in a structure since I need it in shared memory to access and modify as the program runs.

```
struct Umaps {std::unordered_map<int, int> *node_index;} ;
```

I then initialize the unordered_map, node_index, in another function.

```
Umapsptr->node_index = new std::unordered_map<int, int>();
```

Where Umapsptr is the pointer to the Umaps structure in my function. I then try to insert values to the unordered_map.

```
Umapsptr->node_index[5] = 10;
```

But I get this error and I don't know how to resolve it:

error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::unordered_map<int, int>’ and ‘int’)
Umapsptr->node_index[5] = 10;

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be incredibly appreciated.

Comment: Remember your basic pointer stuffs: If you have a pointer `Type *p`, then `p[n]` says "give me the `Type` object at offset  `n` from the base address held in `p` ". In short, that indexing is wonk. `Umapsptr->node_index->at(5) = 10;` will do what you want.

Comment: What's this "shared memory" thing you are talking about? Are you talking about sharing memory between processes or between different parts of your code?  If the former, you'll hit some trouble sharing a C++ object like that across processes. If the latter, in which you really meant to say "global memory", no problem.

Comment: Thank you @WhozCraig!! I see that now. I meant global memory @selbie, thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying `[]` to a pointer does pointer arithmetic.  You want to apply the `[]` to the pointed at object, so you need to explicitly dereference the pointer:

```
(*Umapsptr->node_index)[5] = 10;
```

If you know the key `5` is already in the map, you can use `at` instead:

```
Umapsptr->node_index->at(5) = 10;
```

but this will throw an exception if the key is not present.  If you know the key is not present, you can use emplace:

```
Umapsptr->node_index->emplace(5, 10);
```

but this will do nothing if the key is already present with a different value.